# standardising using standard deviation

Tags: r, k-means, knn, standardized

I'm using R and I'm applying k means after standardizing but I can't figure out how to standardize the data using the standard deviation. I have the code for standardizing using the range but I'm not sure how to use the standard deviation instead

```
crime <-structure(c(2, 2.2, 2, 3.6, 3.5, 4.6, 10.7, 5.2, 5.5, 5.5, 6,
              8.9, 11.3, 3.1, 2.5, 1.8, 9.2, 1, 4, 3.1, 4.4, 4.9, 9, 31, 7.1,
              5.9, 8.1, 8.6, 11.2, 11.7, 6.7, 10.4, 10.1, 11.2, 8.1, 12.8,
              8.1, 13.5, 2.9, 3.2, 5.3, 7, 11.5, 9.3, 3.2, 12.6, 5, 6.6, 11.3,
              8.6, 4.8, 14.8, 21.5, 21.8, 29.7, 21.4, 23.8, 30.5, 33.2, 25.1,
              38.6, 25.9, 32.4, 67.4, 20.1, 31.8, 12.5, 29.2, 11.6, 17.7, 24.6,
              32.9, 56.9, 43.6, 52.4, 26.5, 18.9, 26.4, 41.3, 43.9, 52.7, 23.1,
              47, 28.4, 25.8, 28.9, 40.1, 36.4, 51.6, 17.3, 20, 21.9, 42.3,
              46.9, 43, 25.3, 64.9, 53.4, 51.1, 44.9, 72.7, 31, 28, 24, 22,
              193, 119, 192, 514, 269, 152, 142, 90, 325, 301, 73, 102, 42,
              170, 7, 16, 51, 80, 124, 304, 754, 106, 41, 88, 99, 214, 367,
              83, 208, 112, 65, 80, 224, 107, 240, 20, 21, 22, 145, 130, 169,
              59, 287, 135, 206, 343, 88, 106, 102, 92, 103, 331, 192, 205,
              431, 265, 176, 235, 186, 434, 424, 162, 148, 179, 370, 32, 87,  
              184, 252, 241, 476, 668, 167, 99, 354, 525, 319, 605, 222, 274, 
              408, 172, 278, 482, 285, 354, 118, 178, 243, 329, 538, 437, 180,
              354, 244, 286, 521, 401, 103, 803, 755, 949, 1071, 1294, 1198,
              1221, 1071, 735, 988, 887, 1180, 1509, 783, 1004, 956, 1136,
              385, 554, 748, 1188, 1042, 1296, 1728, 813, 625, 1225, 1340,
              1453, 2221, 824, 1325, 1159, 1076, 1030, 1461, 1787, 2049, 783,
              1003, 817, 1792, 1845, 1908, 915, 1604, 1861, 1967, 1696, 1162,
              1339, 2347, 2208, 2697, 2189, 2568, 2758, 2924, 2822, 1654, 2574,
              2333, 2938, 3378, 2802, 2785, 2801, 2500, 2049, 1939, 2677, 3008,
              3090, 2978, 4131, 2522, 1358, 2423, 2846, 2984, 4373, 1740, 2126,
              2304, 1845, 2305, 3417, 3142, 3987, 3314, 2800, 3078, 4231, 3712,
              4337, 4074, 3489, 4267, 4163, 3384, 3910, 3759, 164, 228, 181,
              906, 705, 447, 637, 776, 354, 376, 328, 628, 800, 254, 288, 158,
              439, 120, 99, 168, 258, 272, 545, 975, 219, 169, 208, 277, 430,
              598, 193, 544, 267, 150, 195, 442, 649, 714, 215, 181, 169, 486,
              343, 419, 223, 478, 315, 402, 762, 604, 328), .Dim = c(51L, 7L
              ), .Dimnames = list(c("ME", "NH", "VT", "MA", "RI", "CT", "NY",
                                    "NJ", "PA", "OH", "IN", "IL", "MI", "WI", "MN", "IA", "MO", "ND",
                                    "SD", "NE", "KS", "DE", "MD", "DC", "VA", "WV", "NC", "SC", "GA",
                                    "FL", "KY", "TN", "AL", "MS", "AR", "LA", "OK", "TX", "MT", "ID",
                                    "WY", "CO", "NM", "AZ", "UT", "NV", "WA", "OR", "CA", "AK", "HI"
              ), c("Murder", "Rape", "Robbery", "Assault", "Burglary", "Theft",
                   "Vehicle")))
crime <- as.data.frame(crime)
sapply(crime, var)
rge <- sapply(crime, function(x) diff(range(x)))
crime_s <- sweep(crime, 2, rge, FUN = "/")
sapply(crime_s, var)
```

Comment: it might help if you give us a sample of `crime` or show us where to get it

Comment: @r2evans I just added it.

Comment: I'd probably use the `scale` function which centers and scales for you, `crime_s = crime; crime_s[] = lapply(crime_s, scale)`.